# Quitting an electron app after setInterval() from external script file

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Edited for more clarity.

I am trying to make a splash screen applet - to start learning nodejs and electron.

I want to create an applet that launches, shows some messages every 10 seconds, and then quits.

I'm basing it off the Discord app and Teams where they have pop up loading screens that have a progress bar, and once completed load the full application.

I want to know how to do it before the "load full app" portion kicks in and how to close the splash screen completely.

Currently I have an `index.js`, `index.html`, and a `main.js`.

`index.js` is the electron browser window. `index.html` is the main rendered page, and the `main.js` is the timer to switch the `innerHTML` based on the time from:

```js
// main.js
var startTime       = 0,
    totalTime       = 10,
    timeBuffer      = 2,
    totalPercent    = 0,
    timeCounter     = setInterval( progress, 1000 );

function progress() {
    if( (startTime += 1) >= (totalTime + timeBuffer + 1) ) {
        // quit app (1)
    } else {
        // show messages here
    }
}
```

At point `(1)` in the code, I've tried adding in `app.close();` but that fails since I haven't added in `app`. I tried adding it in but that doesn't work either.

I tried adding in:

```js
// main.js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
ipcRenderer.send('close-me');

//index.js
ipcMain.on( 'close-me', (evt, arg) => {
    app.quit();
});
```

But this didn't work either. I'm still trying to understand the relationship between `index.js` and the other scripts you might write for the app - but thought quitting the app entirely would be easy.

Comment: Not sure if it is electron specific, but could you please try `setInterval(w.close, 1000)` or `setInterval(w.close.bind(w), 1000)`. Also if the app is quitting,  why `setInterval` and not `setTimeout`?

Comment: @OlehZiniak when i add the first two lines (`const` and `let`) I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: remote.getCurrentWindow is not a function at main.js:4`. `setInterval` because I am counting the timer and animating things at the intervals

Comment: @OlehZiniak updated the question to hopefully make it clearer!

Comment: where is your definition of [`app`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app)? Like `const { app } = require('electron')`

Comment: @pergy `app` is in index.js, but i figured it out as `app.quit()` wasn't working, but `app.exit(0)` was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `app.quit()` wasn't working in this instance, but `app.close(0)` was.

Reading through the docs didn't suggest any reasons to why but in case someone else runs into this problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Store your `setInterval()`as a variable and use JavaScript `clearInterval(variable)` as a page exit action.